# cannot find symbol on declaration of array Class[]

Tags: java

I'm trying to call method from .jar

But when I want to declare array of params for getDeclaredMethod I've got an error "cannot find symbol" on

```
Class[] params = new Class[]{ String };
                              ^
```

Whole method

```
 public void CallCloseWindow(String title){
        //export dll
        InputStream in = staticapi.class.getResourceAsStream("CloseWindow.dll"); 
        File fileOut = new File(System.getProperty("C:\\Java\\CloseWindow.dll")); 
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(fileOut); 
        int c;
        while ((c = in.read()) != -1) { 
            out.write(c);
        }
        in.close(); 
        out.close(); 
        //call from jar class
        Class[] params = new Class[]{ String };
        Object[] parms = new Object[] { new String(title) };
        URL url=new URL("jar:file:/callapi.jar/");
        URLClassLoader ucl = new URLClassLoader(new URL[] { url });
        Class obj = Class.forName("callapi.callapi", true, ucl);
        Method m = obj.getDeclaredMethod("CloseWindow",params);
        Object instance = obj.newInstance();
        Object result = m.invoke(instance,parms);
    }
```

What's the problem?String.TYPE doesn't work either

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with `Class[] params = new Class[]{ String.class };`

Comment: This is Java? What kind of construct is that - `new Class[]{ String.class }`

Comment: Yes it's Java, you are constructing a Class array with only one element (the String.class).

Comment: @Adel: This is perfectly standard Java (but the bit you've quoted is incomplete and makes no sense without the `new`).

Comment: @Fido - Thank You Very Much, that's pretty powerful.

Comment: I was waiting for several minutes but then forgot about it.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
Class[] params = new Class[]{ String.class };
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, you just missed the `.class`. No need to call `new` when initializing an array on declaration though:

```
Class[] params = { String.class };
```

should do fine. (It is only if you reinitialize the array later on, or if you for instance create an anonymous array you would need `new`.)

In fact, you **don't need to create the `params` array at all**. Since `Class.getDeclaredMethods` is a [vararg method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html) you could just do

```
Method m = obj.getDeclaredMethod("CloseWindow", String.class);
                                                \__________/
                                                     |
        this will be transformed to a Class[] on the fly by the constructor
```